# Blazor DI works differently in .razor and business class. Why?

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, blazor

In my Blazor server application I can easily instantiate the class, say, DAL class in .razor part:

```
@page "/"
@inject DAL.DALClass dal
```

and use it in my @code{} scope.

But if I try to instantiate it in my domain logic class like

```
public class ServerDesktopDTO : DesktopDTO
    {
        [Inject]
        protected DAL.DALClass dal { get; set; }
...
```

dal is always null. Why does it work differently? How to inject it to my class using the [Inject] attribute and DI container?

Answer (score 2):

It works differently because components are created by the render engine and not the DI container.
So the `InjectAttribute` has been introduced for Blazor and the render engine look for `InjectAttribute` in components it creates and ask tho the DI contrainer to create the corresponding dependency. But it doesn't look for all classes having `InjectAttribute`.
In other classes use the constructor injection to provide dependencies if you use the default DI container. Other DI container such as Unity or Autfac can inject dependencies per property or method.

Comment: This Blazor way looks like semidecision. Is there any way to make the .NET Core DI give it to me in my business class? Anyway, I feel like falling back on same old ASP.NET Session to keep scope-wide dependencies and use it from here. Bad.

Comment: Constructor injection is rather painless, no reason "to go back to Session".

Comment: Well... It means that I have to trail the dal instance from .razor origin down to all my business classes? And no constructor of all those classes are parameterless longer?

Comment: @Mabanza Nope, it's mean you need to create a business service where you inject the DAL in the constructor and inject this service in components to ask it to create your DTOs.

Comment: I do it exactly this way. But what I end up is making the "component" aka .razor to pass that service to my business classes.  Because the "component" is the only place where [Inject] works.The Class1 should now have constructor Class1(DAL). If it uses instance of Class2, it has to pass that DAL propagated from .razor to it. So the Class2 should have constructor Class2(DAL), and so long and so forth. This is awkward. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: No, that should be be resolved by the DI, you just have to register your class in the services collection.